# USB Boot Issue on Razer Blade Stealth 2020

Tags: system-installation, laptop, intel

So to first give you a bit of information: This is the first time im trying to use Linux. Im using a Razer Blade Stealth 2020 with an i7-10th Gen processor and an Nvidia GTX 1650ti Super-Max-Q.

I downloaded EOS (5.1.7 Hera) and made a bootable usb-drive via Rufus. Now on startup, when choosing to boot from the usb-stick I get the following lines of code on a black screen (right after I see that EOS will boot in 10 sec.)

```
[   0.155052] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
[   0.155061] DMAR: [DMA Write] Request device [57:00.0] PASID ffffffff fault a 
ddr 0 [fault reason 05] PTE Write access is not set
[   0.3397271] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [VRTC] (0000000052591dcd) [Syst
emCMOS] (20190816/evregion-132)
[   0.339735] ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler (20190816/exf
ldio-265)
[   0.339745] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC10.LPCB.ECO.RTEC due to previo
us error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20190816/psparse-531)
[   0.339752] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC10.LPCB.ECO._REC due to previo
us error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20190816/psparse-531)
[   2.357090] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
[   2.357529] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
[   2.357967] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
[   2.358399] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
[   2.357832] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
[   2.359265] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
[   2.359697] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
[   2.360130] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
```

I figured that the last lines regarding the tpm chip can be resolved by deactivating secure boot and some tpm-specific settings in BIOS. However even then the first lines will still appear, just without the error codelines for the tpm chip. EOS will still not boot.

Does anyone have any idea how I can resolve this and get EOS to boot?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

quote:

> As I've learned, the error is because dmar tables or my BIOS are
> broken..

[source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=176398)

Maybe try Firmware Test Suite > [dmar test](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FirmwareTestSuite/Reference/dmar)

More [info](https://github.com/linuxkit/linux/blob/master/Documentation/Intel-IOMMU.txt)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how or why but I was now able to boot from usb and install. Only issue now is that none of my audio input or output devices are regocnized